# Swift: identifying variable failing

Tags: ios, variables, swift

I have an IBOutlet called  `patternRoom` but in my code I receive an error.

```
@IBOutlet private weak var patternRoom: UIImageView!

struct gameBegin {
    var playBegin: Bool {
        didSet {
            if playBegin == true {
                println("\(playBegin)")
                // for goes in (up to 3) (up to 5) (up to 10)

                var swipes = Menu()

                if (swipes.no_of_swipes) == 3 {
                    //blahdeblah
                    for i in 0 ..< 3 {
                        patternRoom.image = UIImage(named: "pattern24.png")
                        //error here 'Game.type does not have a member named patternRoom'
                    }

                }

                if (swipes.no_of_swipes) == 5 {
                    //blahdeblah
                }

                if (swipes.no_of_swipes) == 10 {
                    //blahdeblah
                }


            }
            // display picture 1
            // check user input == picture
            // move ahead or error
            // at end display score e.t.c.

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: patternRoom may not be accessible from inside the struct.

Comment: @rakeshbs So what should I do to change that?

Comment: is it necessary for you to use a struct there? Either assign an uiimageview variable inside the struct or move the code outside the struct

Comment: Can't you just get rid of the `struct` and have `playBegin` be a normal `Bool` class instance variable? You can't access patternRoom from within that struct.

Comment: @trevorj I like the idea, if you could answer and include details on how to do this, I'll tick and +1. Thanks

Comment: @WilliamClark Literally delete `struct gameBegin {` and the closing `}`. I am assuming that all of this is in a class of some sort, like the view controller that `patternRoom` is an outlet in. As long as `playBegin` is an instance variable in a class that `patternRoom` is an outlet in, you shouldn't have to change anything else in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure that the following is all in a class (like your view controller) and it should work fine.

```
@IBOutlet weak var patternRoom: UIImageView!

    var playBegin: Bool {
        didSet {
            if playBegin == true {
                println("\(playBegin)")
                // for goes in (up to 3) (up to 5) (up to 10)

                var swipes = Menu()

                if (swipes.no_of_swipes) == 3 {
                    //blahdeblah
                    for i in 0 ..< 3 {
                        patternRoom.image = UIImage(named: "pattern24.png")
                        //error here 'Game.type does not have a member named patternRoom'
                    }

                }

                if (swipes.no_of_swipes) == 5 {
                    //blahdeblah
                }

                if (swipes.no_of_swipes) == 10 {
                    //blahdeblah
                }


            }
            // display picture 1
            // check user input == picture
            // move ahead or error
            // at end display score e.t.c.

        }
    }
```